# "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" When Using Boto3 to Access S3 from Lambda Localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, localstack

While using Localstack, I'm facing a problem with accessing an S3 bucket (or any resources) from a lambda function. I'm using the [`tflocal`](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/terraform/#using-the-tflocal-script) command as a wrapper around terraform command, and I'm using the regular aws cli.

My file structure is as follows:

```
.
├── /lambda_dump
│   └── lambda_function.zip
├── /lambda_functions
│   └── handler.py
├── main.tf
```

#### Terraform Config

```
# main.tf

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "accesskey"
  secret_key = "secretkey"
  region     = "ca-central-1"
  profile    = "localstack"

  s3_use_path_style           = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  endpoints {
    s3     = "http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566"
    lambda = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "test-lambda-bucket"
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambda_functions/handler.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_dump/lambda_function.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_s3_lambda" {
  filename      = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path
  function_name = "test_s3_lambda"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/UnusedRole"
  handler       = "handler.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.7"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path)

  environment {
    variables = {
      BUCKET_NAME = aws_s3_bucket.b.bucket
      S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Lambda Function

```py
# lambda_functions/handler.py
import json
import boto3
import os

s3 = boto3.client('s3'
                  endpoint_url=os.environ['S3_ENDPOINT_URL'],
                  aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                  aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                 )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME')
        
        s3.put_object(Body='Hello, World!', 
                    Bucket=bucket_name, 
                    Key='test.txt')

        result = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, 
                            Key='test.txt')
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
            },
            'body': json.dumps({
                'environment': json.dumps(os.environ),
                's3 response': json.loads(result["Body"].read())
                })
        }
    except Exception as e:
            return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
                },
                'body': json.dumps({"environment": dict(os.environ),
                                    'e': e}, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
            }
```

#### Zipping Lambda Function

The lambda function is located in `lambda_functions/handler.py`, and we want to zip this file into the `lambda_dump/lambda.zip` file.

```bash
zip -r lambda_dump/lambda_function.zip lambda_functions/handler.py
```

#### Applying Changes

```bash
$ tflocal init
$ tflocal apply --auto-approve
```

This runs successfully as expected.

#### Invoking Lambda Function

Since it might be important, here are my AWS credentials files:

```
# ~/.aws/credentials
[localstack]
aws_access_key_id=accesskey
aws_secret_access_key=secretkey

# ~/.aws/config
[profile localstack]
region=ca-central-1
output = json
```

According to the localstack documentation, we can invoke the lambda function using the following command:

```bash
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=mock_access_key \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mock_secret_key \
aws lambda invoke \
--profile=localstack \
--region=ca-central-1 \
--endpoint=http://localhost:4566 \
--function-name test_s3_lambda \
lambda_output.json

{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

#### Lambda Output

```json
{
    "e": "An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.",
    "environment": {
        "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "LSIARZPUZDIKLGAEPUMU",
        "AWS_CONTAINER_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN": "0a9569e2-2817-44c2-8206-8b1d1ced4551",
        "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI": "http://127.0.0.1:9001/2021-04-23/credentials",
        "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "ca-central-1",
        "AWS_ENDPOINT_URL": "http://172.17.0.2:4566",
        "AWS_EXECUTION_ENV": "AWS_Lambda_python3.7",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE": "128",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME": "test_s3_lambda",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT": "3",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION": "$LATEST",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_INITIALIZATION_TYPE": "on-demand",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME": "/aws/lambda/test_s3_lambda",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME": "2023/07/03/[$LATEST]6aa29fe0c74664342d6d958f86b84a4a",
        "AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API": "127.0.0.1:9001",
        "AWS_REGION": "ca-central-1",
        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "2vZBGFWpqXjssPFWJHqOBbKSj6gyhWPp/MEMuYdG",
        "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN": "FQoGZXIvYXdzEBYaDOXWGWEq+XQ9f8VRfatkpzLWT4MZMXU2XQO8CL6Gj5REtPWICVtB1VOskK6J/+IyGb99IwakG1YC+gW9SDvmiNHF4ive0R/kBjbgtAAqr7bpL7xqScpmfhuZVLjAheWg2SVLgLZ6R8Rm3C9FOqycO8gCuRrAft7NmFqQtdZ44jgaHVpDINyqytB9wa5vASkP8M834HKpelJ+j+URekt4q2q1BAxHJlEw9CtKsgHw12QEwSjmNIWRaPUHAZAAgD0qqFSH7kb2z4FgD1AVonTkggr8F22ANTfpwHBaqauo7WXGgMAjQzkGcX3WN3/cEzOzIMwVADYaK4ZtOl4/RDA=",
        "AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING": "LOG_ERROR",
        "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS": "127.0.0.1:2000",
        "BUCKET_NAME": "test-lambda-bucket",
        "EDGE_PORT": "4566",
        "LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR": "/var/runtime",
        "LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT": "/var/task",
        "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8",
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib",
        "LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME": "172.17.0.2",
        "PATH": "/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin",
        "TZ": ":UTC",
        "_AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS": "127.0.0.1",
        "_AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_PORT": "2000",
        "_HANDLER": "handler.lambda_handler",
        "_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID": "Root=1-64a33c31-a34782b2aaefc751652619ef;Parent=06c6562472495e44;Sampled=0"
    }
}
```

The problem here is indicated by the error message in the "body" field:

```json
"e": "An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."
```

This error suggests that my AWS credentials are not being passed to the lambda function. But I thought this wouldn't matter when using localstack? Does anyone know what the problem could be? Or how I can debug this more easily?